# .htaccess Folder redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I try to make redirect in my folder:

```
Redirect /promotion/ /newpromotion
Redirect /promotion/first/ /new/first/
```

And now if I try to open `http://mysite.com/promotion/first` I open `http://mysite.com/newpromotion/new/first` but I need `http://mysite.com/new/first`

How can I fix it?

**UPD:**
It's crazy but I did it:

```
   Redirect /promotion/ /newpromotion
   Redirect /promotion/first/ /new/first/
   Redirect /newpromotion/new/first /new/first/
```

**Solution:**
Need to reverse the 2 directives:

```
Redirect /promotion/first /new/first
Redirect /promotion /newpromotion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

Redirect /promotion/first/ /new/first/
Redirect /promotion/ /newpromotion

the more detailed should come first.

----- EDIT ------

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/promotion/first/$ /new/first/ [L]
RewriteRule ^/promotion/$ /newpromotion/ [L]
```

Comment: Redirect /promotion/first/ /new/first/ Redirect /promotion/ /newpromotion  - work

Answer (score 1):

`Redirect` directive connects to path nodes together, so when you have:

```
Redirect /promotion/ /newpromotion
```

It means **anything** *starting* with `/promotion/` gets redirected to `/newpromotion/`. e.g:

- `/promotion/` -> `/newpromotion/`
- `/promotion/foo.html` -> `/newpromotion/foo.html`
- `/promotion/first/` -> `/newpromotion/first/`

You just need to reverse the 2 directives:

```
Redirect /promotion/first /new/first
Redirect /promotion /newpromotion
```

Comment: @NickBrit [As you can see, it works fine for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BXLwD.png), either you have other rules or redirects that's conflicting, or you aren't describing the problem correctly.